# Security & Privacy is not responding

Tags: macos, catalina, performance, system-settings

I need to change enable camera for Google Chrome. So I go to System Preferences > **Security & Privacy** and it hangs.

Console log:

```
Dec 13 07:17:37 macabook com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.remoteservice.30883): 
Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = 
/Library/Apple/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.SafariServices.ExtensionHelper.xpc error = 122: 
Path had bad ownership/permissions, origin = 
/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice.xpc

Dec 13 07:17:37 macabook com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.remoteservice.30883): 
Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = 
/Library/Apple/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.SafariServices.xpc error = 122: 
Path had bad ownership/permissions, origin = 
/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice.xpc

Dec 13 07:17:37 macabook com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice[30883]: objc[30883]: 
Class AWDSecurityPrefAutoUnlockSetup is implemented in both 
/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice (0x107217768) 
and 
/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/Security (0x109b34180). 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I tried: reboot, safe mode, cleaning `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration` folder. Nothing helps.

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
Catalina 10.15.1

Comment: Thread on Apple forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250940919